# Git creates extra branch when merging

Tags: git, version-control, merge, gitlab

I have two git branches R1609 and R1609_dpl in my gitlab.

Every time I push something to R1609 I want to merge those changes into R1609_dpl using a trigger.
For some reason git creates an extra branch just for a merge commit. The Commit History looks like this after a merge:

[image: Network]

The commit "Merge branch X of URL into X" seems completely unnecessary.
My code for the merge:

```
git checkout R1609
git pull origin R1609
git checkout R1609_dpl
git pull origin R1609_dpl
git merge --no-ff R1609
git commit --amend -m "Push to R1609 triggered: Merge R1609 into R1609_dpl"
git push origin R1609_dpl
```

What am I missing? I want to get rid of the extra branch and simply merge right into the R1609_dpl branch without having two merge commits.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Got rid of the

```
git commit --amend -m "Push to R1609 triggered: Merge R1609 into R1609_dpl"
```

and added a rebase but still no luck

```
git checkout R1609
git pull origin R1609
git checkout R1609_dpl
git pull origin R1609_dpl
git merge --no-ff R1609
#Added rebase
git pull --rebase origin R1609_dpl
git push origin R1609_dpl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `git pull` *means* `git merge`.

Well, it means "First run `git fetch`, then run `git merge` unless I tell you to run `git rebase` as your second step instead."

You therefore have *four* items that potentially—we'll get back to the "potentially" part in a minute—create merges:

1. `git checkout R1609; git pull origin R1609`: this may create a new merge commit on your current (i.e., `R1609`) branch, using whatever it finds and fetches from your upstream, i.e., the *other* (origin's) Git's `R1609`.
2. `git checkout R1609_dpl; git pull origin R1609_dpl`.  As with step 1, this potentially creates a new merge commit.
3. `git merge --no-ff R1609`: this *definitely* creates a merge commit, unless it does nothing at all.  (It had best not do nothing because of item 4 here.)
4. `git commit --amend -m "Push to R1609 triggered: Merge R1609 into R1609_dpl"`: this "amend" copies the current commit to a new commit with a new, different message.  It shoves the current commit aside.  Assuming we made a merge in step 3, this shoves the merge aside and replaces it with a new merge.  The shoved-aside merge will vanish from `git log` output, since the current *branch* (now `R1609_dpl`) points to the new copy and only its reflog points to the original, once the amend finishes.

In some ways, then, it's a bit surprising that you don't get *three* commits.  The one you *are* getting is coming from step 1, since the log shows that its message is "Merge branch 'R1609' of <url> into R1609".  So now it's time to describe the "potentially" thing.

There are two possibilities for `git fetch`, and the second one splits into two cases:

- The upstream, which your Git calls `origin/R1609` but their (origin's) Git just calls `R1609`, is in sync with your own `R1609`, or is behind: you have some commit(s) they lack (until you push them).  In this case, `git fetch` does nothing, and there is nothing to merge, and `git merge` does nothing.  (Yay, but also boo, why did we even bother? :-) Well, to check, of course.)
- The upstream is not in sync with your `R1609`.  Git fetches some commit(s) from the upstream.  This could be *strictly ahead* of your own commit(s) on your `R1609`, or it might be the case that their `R1609` has a commit that you lack, while your `R1609` has a commit that they lack.  The `fetch` step does not need to care; it just brings in whichever commits they have, that you don't.  It then updates your `origin/R1609` to remember their new commit(s).<sup>1</sup>

When fetch *does* bring something in, though, you may now be *strictly behind*—you just need to catch up to their `R1609`—or you may be simultaneously ahead *and* behind.  In the former case, `git merge` defaults to doing a "fast forward" operation.<sup>2</sup>  Git changes your branch label, `R1609`, so that it points to the same commit as their `R1609` (your `origin/R1609`).  Of course, if you specify `--no-ff`, Git makes a real merge instead.  In the latter case, though, Git *must* make a real merge, to combine your commit(s) and their commit(s).  So you get a merge here, and its message is `Merge branch 'R1609' of <url> into R1609`.

Clearly, then, something upstream is causing new commits to appear on *their* `R1609`, which your Git finds it must merge in step 1 above.  Nothing happens to the upstream `R1609_dpl` so your Git is able to fast-forward, or do nothing at all, as appropriate, in step 2.  Step 3 creates a new merge and step 4 shoves it aside while creating a third merge, leaving you with the two visible merges.

(I see that by the time I finished writing all this, you already found the culprit that's introducing a commit on `R1609` on `origin`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, as long as your Git is version 1.8.4 or newer.  Older Git versions sometimes fail to update the remote-tracking branch.  (Specifically, they deliberately do not update it on the `fetch` run from the `pull` script.  This turned out to be a mistake, so it was changed in 1.8.4.)

<sup>2</sup>Although the `git merge` documentation describes this as a *fast-forward merge*, it's really not a merge at all.  Fast-forward is a property of a *label move*.  Given a label that points to commit X, and a request to change it to point to label Y, we test: "Is X an ancestor of Y?"  If so, this change is a fast-forward.  If not, it's not.

Both `git fetch` and `git pull` have built-in code to detect fast-forward moves, vs non-fast-forward moves.  This is what the `--force` flag is all about, when pushing—and for that matter, when fetching, although for fetch it's invariably done via the `+` syntax in a refspec instead.  Without `--force` or the `+` flag, Git refuses to change a branch label from commit X to commit Y unless commit X is an ancestor of Y.

The `merge` command, of course, also has this same code, and will fast-forward the label instead of merging, provided (a) this is possible and (b) you have not forbidden it.  Since this operation is being done on the *current branch*, using the current index and work-tree, `git merge` also updates the index and work-tree to match.  The fetch and push code update neither the index nor the work-tree.

Comment: This clarifies a lot! I managed to fix the issue be rewriteing part of my bash script and rearanging it. Never got an answer this detailed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no "extra" branch.  What you are seeing is merely a graphical interpretation of what is actually happening in Git.  Here is a diagram showing the first two steps of your merge process:

```
R1609:     _____
R1609_dpl: _____\_______   (R1609_dpl after merge with R1609)
```

If you only had a simple merge, without amending the commit, your diagram should look something like what I have above.  Namely, you can see that `R1609` comes into `R1609-dpl` at some point.

However, you did the following additional step:

```
git commit --amend -m "Push to R1609 triggered: Merge R1609 into R1609_dpl"
```

You *amended* (read: rewrote) the merge commit.  This means that the original merge commit is no longer a part of the `R1609_dpl` branch.  My hunch is that your graphical tool is attempting to show this by having a separate brown line.  You will notice that this "branch" (it's not really a branch) only seems to have one commit.  This commit is your original merge commit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But even if I delete the commit amend I get two commits for my merge and the diagram looks the same. 1. "Merge branch 'R1609' into R1609_dpl" 2. "Merge branch 'R1609' of URL into R1609". I would like just one merge commit

Comment: `I get two commits for my merge and the diagram looks the same.` ... I don't believe this.  You should be getting one commit.

Comment: I deleted the whole commit --amend code and left everything else the same. The only thing that changes is that the first commit now reads "Merge branch 'R1609' into R1609_dpl" instead of "Push to R1609 triggered: Merge R1609 into R1609_dpl". Doesn't make sense to me either